# R Shiny: Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for vertica DB

Tags: r, rjdbc

Getting below error while using **vertica** copy table from local.

Please suggest

> Error:Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for COPY
>   Monetisation_Base_table FROM LOCAL 'E://testCSV.csv' delimiter ','
>   ([Vertica]JDBC A ResultSet was expected but not generated
>   from query "COPY Monetisation_Base_table FROM LOCAL 'E://testCSV.csv'
>   delimiter ','". Query not executed. )

Code Used:

```
library(RJDBC)
vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath="full\path\to\driver\vertica_jdbc_VERSION.jar")
vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://30.0.9.163:5433/db", "sk14930IU", "Snapdeal_40")
myframe = dbGetQuery(vertica, "COPY Monetisation_Base_table FROM LOCAL 'E://testCSV.csv' delimiter ','"")
```

Comment: IMHO, you should add the rjdbc tag to your question.

Answer (score 3):

dbSendUpdate should do the work in this case .

Comment: It works fine on Linux. However on WIndows it says " Cant open file for reading. No such file or directory". I tried to specify path multiple ways. Do you know any workaroud ?